# Select options in form from other table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Good evening,

I have the following situation:

I have 2 tables:

Table 1 (Person)
Name
Adress
Sex

Table 2 (Sex)
ID
Sex (Values: Male/Female/Unkown)

I've made a form in PHP to fill in the name and adress, and a different form to manage the sexes.

What i want to do is the following: I want to link the column Sex from table 1, to colum sex in table 2.

I want to create a dropdown menu in my php form, to show the sex values from table 2, select a sex, and link that person ID to the sex ID.

How can i make this possible?

Edit: My purpose is, if i change a sex name: Like, Man, to Male, i don't have to edit all my persons.

My code right now:

```
    <a href="index.php">Home</a><br>
<a href="personeninvoeren.php">Personen invoeren</a><br>
<a href="personeninvoeren.php">Voertuigen invoeren</a>
<a href="beheergeslacht.php">Geslacht beheren</a>
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','shopqvat_rdw','PASSWORD'); 
mysql_select_db('shopqvat_rdw') or die (mysql_error()); 

if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])) 
  { 
    $persoon_voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
  $persoon_tussenvoegsel = $_POST['tussenvoegsel'];
  $persoon_achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
  $persoon_straatnaam = $_POST['straatnaam'];
  $persoon_huisnummer = $_POST['huisnummer'];
  $persoon_toevoeging = $_POST['toevoeging'];
  $persoon_bsnnummer = $_POST['bsnnummer'];
  $persoon_geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
  $persoon_geslacht = $_POST['geslacht'];

  $sqlgeslacht = "SELECT * FROM geslacht";
$resultgeslacht = mysql_query($sqlgeslacht);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persoon (voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam,
        straatnaam, huisnummer, toevoeging, bsnnummer, geboortedatum, geslacht) VALUES ('".$persoon_voornaam."', '".$persoon_tussenvoegsel."', '".$persoon_achternaam."',
         '".$persoon_straatnaam."', '".$persoon_huisnummer."', '".$persoon_toevoeging."', '".$persoon_bsnnummer."', '".$persoon_geboortedatum."', '".$persoon_geslacht."')") or die (mysql_error()); 

    echo 'Persoon succesvol toegevoegd!'; 
  } 
else 
  { 
?> 
<form action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> " method="POST">
<div>Voornaam <input type='text' name='voornaam' id='voornaam' /></div><br>
<div>Tussenvoegsel <input type='text' name='tussenvoegsel' id='tussenvoegsel' /></div><br>
<div>Achternaam <input type='text' name='achternaam' id='achternaam' /></div><br>
<div>Straatnaam <input type='text' name='straatnaam' id='straatnaam' /></div><br>
<div>Huisnummer <input type='text' name='huisnummer' id='huisnummer' /></div><br>
<div>Toevoeging <input type='text' name='toevoeging' id='toevoeging' /></div><br>
<div>BSN Nummer <input type='text' name='bsnnummer' id='bsnnummer' /></div><br>
<div>Geboortedatum <input type='text' name='geboortedatum' id='geboortedatum' /></div><br>
<div>Geslacht <?php echo"<select name='geslacht' id='geslacht' >";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultgeslacht)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['geslacht'] ."'>" . $row['geslacht'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";?></div><br/>
<input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="verzenden">
</form> 
<? 
  } 
?>
```

EDIT: I have added an array and i am calling the values with an echo, it shows an empty dropdown menu, what am i doing wrong?

It is all about the: "Geslacht", i have a extra table where i define the sexes (geslacht).

So i want to show the values of table2, in this form.. When i choose that value i want it to "link" it with the person ID, so whenever i change the sex title, it changes at the person.

Comment: By writing some code? Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: What area are you having trouble? What have you tried? There are 3 layers to this Data, Application, and Presentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've added my code, i'm trying with the other reply i've gotten with the LEFT join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first Point you can add a LEFT JOIN to your Table.

```
LEFT JOIN <table2> ON <table1>.<field> = <table2>.<field>    
LEFT JOIN Sex ON Person.Sex = Sex.ID
```

Tipp: Make your field names more clear dont use Sex as table and field Name.

You might want to get some more Information over Database Structur, you can get some good hints if you google `Normaliation/Database Relations`

About you seccond Point:

Make a Query to get all records of the Sex Table into an Array. Then do a Loop in PHP and insert into you select field for every Entry in the Array `<option value="_ID_">_SEXTitle_</option>`

When you get youre Form back you just need to enter the select value into you Sex Field of the Person Table.

EDIT:
You Need to Change from an Input to an select: 
Witout the dynamic of PHP/MySQL your plain HTML code should look like this:

```
<div>Geslacht <select type='text' name='geslacht' id='geslacht' >
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
    <option value="3">None ;)</option>
</select></div><br/>
```

Tipp2: NEVER safe Data from a POST/GET Array directly in a Database! At least Escape the entries to [Prevent SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input)

Comment: Thank you very much, i've been kinda in this direction, but i wasn't sure how to use it.. I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: I don't know how good you're German is but you might want to have a look on this side [PHP-Kurs](http://www.php-kurs.com/relationen-tabellen-verbinden.htm) You don't Need to Change anything in your Insert Statement

Comment: Allright, thanks for your tips, i've edited my code to show the values from table: Sex into the dropdown menu, there is showing a dropdown menu but isn't showing the values. I've edited my starting post. I've gone through different tutorials to show the values in an array. Am i missing something?

Comment: Extra comment: Thanks for your additional tips, i will follow them up as soon i've hang the hang of the dropdown arrays and the LEFT JOIN.